# Rails: Errors after invalid record creation does not show up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I am trying to create a simple app which allows a logged in user(who belongs to a group - groups table) creates a group transactions.However, I do not get any errors after I've submitted an invalid form(I have validations).

Here is my controller:

```
class GroupTransactionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :get_group, only: [:new, :create, :destroy, :index, :show]
  before_action :how_many_members, only: [:new, :show, :create]
  before_action :set_transaction_number, only: [:index]

  def new
    @group_transaction = @group.group_transactions.new
    @members.times { @group_transaction.group_transaction_borrowers.build }
  end 

  def create
    @group_transaction = @group.group_transactions.build(group_transactions_params)

    if @group_transaction.save
      flash[:success] = "Group transactions has been made"
      redirect_to group_group_transactions_path(@group)
    else  
      render 'new' 
    end
  end

  private

  def group_transactions_params
    params.require(:group_transaction).permit(:issuer_id, :value, :description, 
                                          group_transaction_borrowers_attributes: 
                            GroupTransactionBorrower.attribute_names.map(&:to_sym))
    #output of the line above: [:id, :created_at, :updated_at, :group_transactions_id, 
     :borrower_id]                                                                                                                                               
  end 

  def get_group
    @group = Group.find(params[:group_id])
  end 

  def how_many_members
    @members = Group.find(params[:group_id]).relations.count 
  end 

end
```

Here is GroupTransaction model:

```
class GroupTransaction < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :group_transaction_borrowers, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :issuer, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "issuer_id"
  belongs_to :group

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :group_transaction_borrowers, reject_if: :ignore_empty

  #basic validations
  validates :value, presence: true, numericality: { greater_than: 0 }
  validates :description, presence: true, length: { maximum: 20 }


  validates_associated :group_transaction_borrowers 
  validates_presence_of :group_transaction_borrowers

  def ignore_empty(attributes)
    attributes['borrower_id'].blank?
  end 

end
```

Here is GroupTransactionBorrower model:

```
class GroupTransactionBorrower < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :group_transaction
  belongs_to :borrower, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "borrower_id"
  validates :borrower_id, presence: true
end
```

Here is my view for new action of the GroupTransactionsController:

```
<%= provide(:title, "New group transaction") %>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
  <%= form_with(model: [@group, @group_transaction],url: 
      group_group_transactions_path,class: "new_transaction") do |f| %>
    <!-- show error messages render error partial -->
    <%= render "shared/error_group_transactions" %>

    <%= hidden_field_tag "group_transaction[issuer_id]", current_user.id %>

  
    <%= f.fields_for :group_transaction_borrowers do |borrower| %>  
      <%= borrower.label :borrower_id, "Borrower name" %>
      <%= borrower.collection_select(:borrower_id, group_members(@group.id), :id, :name,
                            { include_blank: 'Please select borrower' }) %>

    <% end %>

    <%= label_tag :value, "Value" %>
    <%= f.number_field :value, step: 0.01 %>

    <%= label_tag :description, "Description" %>
    <%= f.text_field :description %>

    <%= f.submit "Make Transaction!", class: "btn btn-primary" %>

  <% end %>
</div>
```

_error_group_transactions partial:

```
<% if @group_transaction.errors.any? %>
 <div id="error_explanation">
    <!-- show how many errors -->
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
      <%= pluralize(@group_transaction.errors.count, "error") %> occured 
      <!-- show the errors content -->
    </div>
      <ul>
        <% @group_transaction.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <%= msg %>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I  use nested routes, which are defined as followed:

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
   #other routes
   resources :groups do 
     resources :group_transactions, only: [:destroy, :show, :create, :new, :index]
   end
 end
```

When I submit form with empty fields I do not get error messages.However it is seemed that the _error_group_transactions partial is rendered(check logs info bellow).
Logs after I submitted form with empty fields:

```
Started POST "/groups/6/group_transactions" for ::1 at 2020-10-18 16:46:04 +0200
   (0.1ms)  SELECT sqlite_version(*)
Processing by GroupTransactionsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"3GVrvgeGCZ/UMVy5He9LA3d96A5uchEeDknUxduNiuvQYJE2UDeyzarcOrApD2pYYSSMAHLzwBrE3acK9aBkhw==", "group_transaction"=>{"issuer_id"=>"21", "group_transaction_borrowers_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"borrower_id"=>""}, "1"=>{"borrower_id"=>""}}, "value"=>"", "description"=>""}, "commit"=>"Make Transaction!", "group_id"=>"6"}
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 21], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/helpers/session_helper.rb:27:in `current_user'
  Group Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "groups".* FROM "groups" WHERE "groups"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 6], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/group_transactions_controller.rb:77:in `get_group'
  CACHE Group Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "groups".* FROM "groups" WHERE "groups"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 6], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/group_transactions_controller.rb:81:in `how_many_members'
   (0.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "relations" WHERE "relations"."group_id" = ?  [["group_id", 6]]
  ↳ app/controllers/group_transactions_controller.rb:81:in `how_many_members'
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 21], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/group_transactions_controller.rb:21:in `create'
  Rendering group_transactions/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  <h2>Rendered shared/_error_group_transactions.html.erb (Duration: 16.8ms | Allocations: 551)</h2>
  Rendered group_transactions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 40.3ms | Allocations: 1051)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (Duration: 0.0ms | Allocations: 5)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (Duration: 1.7ms | Allocations: 358)
  Rendered shared/_flash_messages.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 17)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 27)
Completed 200 OK in 508ms (Views: 217.4ms | ActiveRecord: 2.6ms | Allocations: 37732)
```

I can provide additional code if you want.
I would appreciate any help from you.
Thanks in advance,
Lukas

Comment: On a side note `hidden_field_tag "group_transaction[issuer_id]", current_user.id` smells like a major security problem. Its makes it trivial for a malicous user to use the web inspector or cURL to send whatever id they want. Instead use the session which is harder to tamper with as its an encrypted cookie.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by by creating a proper generic errors partial by using a local variable instead of an instance variable:

```
# shared/errors.html.erb
<% if object.errors.any? %>
 <div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
      <%= pluralize(object.errors.count, "error") %> occured 
    </div>
      <ul>
        <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This changes your partial from something thats dependentent on the state of the view context to a simple function where you just provide input and it renders HTML. It can thus render the errors for any given model.

Then render the errors for your main object and the errors for each nested object:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
  <%= form_with(model: [@group, @group_transaction], url: 
      group_group_transactions_path, class: "new_transaction") do |f| %>
    <%= render "shared/errors", object: f.object %>

    <%= hidden_field_tag "group_transaction[issuer_id]", current_user.id %>

    <%= f.fields_for :group_transaction_borrowers do |borrower| %>  
      <%# renders the errors for this borrower %>
      <%= render "shared/errors", object: borrower.object %>
      <%= borrower.label :borrower_id, "Borrower name" %>
      <%= borrower.collection_select(:borrower_id, group_members(@group.id), :id, :name,
                            { include_blank: 'Please select borrower' }) %>
    <% end %>

    <%= label_tag :value, "Value" %>
    <%= f.number_field :value, step: 0.01 %>
    <%= label_tag :description, "Description" %>
    <%= f.text_field :description %>
    <%= f.submit "Make Transaction!", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```